# Photoshop questions

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, migration

Over on photo.stackexchange.com we have gotten quite a few photoshop related questions that are outside the realm of photography, but would probably fall into the graphic design space.

How does the Graphic Design community feel about [photoshop questions being migrated](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/what-should-we-do-with-photoshop-questions) over from the Photography site?

Possible examples:

- https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6234/how-do-i-turn-off-anti-aliasing-while-drawing-shapes-in-photoshop
- https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5062/how-do-i-get-this-glare-effect
- https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4474/how-do-i-convert-a-color-transparent-png-to-white-not-bw-transparent-png

Comment: In the same vein... looks like this one http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/498/how-can-you-remove-grain-from-photographs might be a good candidate to migrate to photography :)

Comment: Do you have any examples?

Comment: Here's an example that got migrated: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/703/

Answer (score 7):

I'm in favor. I think migrating questions like these helps us:

1. increase activity on the site: more questions per day > more potential answers > more potential reputation > more potential avid users
2. increase awareness of the site: people from other stack exchange sites will follow the re-direct to our community.

I think these should be our aims during beta (all while maintaining quality answers and number of answers - those these should hopefully come partly as a result of 1. and 2.)

Further note: I've noticed similar questions on superuser that would make more sense on our site.

Comment: Yeah, superuser has quite a few photoshop questions that would probably now fit better on graphic design or photography, depending on the viewpoint...

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Jaips in that  these questions would be okay to have, **as long as a minimum standard of quality is enforced for *questions* as well**. If the site starts getting flooded with "How do I do a design like on this web site plz send PSD thx" questions, I'm out.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to keep under control the question about Photoshop. I'll rather prefer that people would search in google first and than ask a question about Photoshop. People good at using a tool are not Designers, even if the majority of Graphic Designer (because they work with) know how to.

I am for welcoming as well the questions from photography, with a reserve/filter. I feel a bit undermined as profession to answer question like "how do you do a diagonal in photoshop?" instead of talking about design principle or solutions.

Comment: Stackexchange communities are successful on scale, they need to be a recognized name for finding answers. if the answer is better found on google (i.e some other link from google, not the stackexchange link) then the community will fizzle in obscurity. Stack overflow is not successful because its one of a few good places to find programmer answers, its successful because it is the *best* place to find programmer answers

Comment: i've thought about this some more, and i think you have a good point. In the early stages of a stackexchange sites life it is important to have a balance of tough, expert-engaging questions to encourage the community to attract more experts. The community will be built around, highly skilled, highly knowledgable, and highly engaged users.