# Creating a firm plan to increase readership: Let's get out the vote!

Tags: discussion, beta

I'm bumping up this topic so that it doesn't fall by the wayside. There have been a couple questions already about this ([here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/should-we-increase-this-ses-scope) and on [Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/374/6313)). I'm starting a new thread with the clear goal of formulating a clear plan to get this site in gear and to give us a clean slate in which to work.

I'll post an answer that is my idea to move forward for folks to vote on and for others to propose their own. That will make this a poll-type question, but I think it's time we put all of the ideas in one place and get a consensus on what to do next.

I think we are pretty far into the beta period and the health of the site has some serious issues, so speed is important. But please take the time to carefully read, propose, and vote.

This site has a ton of potential and I think we all really want to see it succeed. Let's get this site out of beta if only so that we can see what design @Jin and his gang can come up with for a site about design, a challenge if there ever was one.

Answer (score 15):

My favorite plan out of the bunch is the one suggested by `@Patrick McElhaney` from UI.SE:

> If Graphic Design wants to expand its
>   definition to cover UI, typography,
>   comics, or any other subject, I don't
>   see any reason why it shouldn't. Go
>   ahead and make the best site you can;
>   don't let other proposals stand in
>   your way.

We can discuss what's appropriate for "Design" and what's not all day, but those ideas are stuck in committee, and no one has been able to really agree upon what is appropriate or not (UI, fashion design), even with Joel Spolsky's guideline of using a university department as a guideline simply because universities handle design differently from each other.

I suggest **re-do/re-open/re-name "Graphic Design" to simply "Design"**. (Guidance from the SE Valued Employees would be helpful here).

**The overall theme I think we should embrace would be to focus on the motif—style, decoration, theme, aesthetic—of a project regardless of medium** in the following manner (the lists are examples and not all-inclusive):

**Focus on 2D design**

- Graphic arts - logo design, fonts &
  typography, visual communication,
  etc.
- Web design - CSS-centric/HTML-inclusive
- UI/UX Design
- Typography and typesetting
- Layout and printing
- Branding and marketing
- photographic design
- illustration
- Comics
- Digital media - (i.e., Flash, Video)
- Technical questions (How-To) related to design applications, or at least those applications that have the broadest audience, like Adobe Photoshop, Illustrator, and InDesign.

**Allow 3D design (and leave it to a question of what will gain traction)**

- fashion design
- industrial design
- Spacial (Interior/Exterior) Design
- Sculpture

**Disallow the following (knowing that some of this might be self-contradictory)**

- Technical questions related to 3D software
- Technical suestions related to Video editing software
- Web site *architecture and development* (i.e., pure HTML/no CSS, questions related to the back
  end)
- Landscaping and Architecture (though this may contradict allowing interior and exterior design)

That being said, oftentimes we can't apply a design or aesthetic to a project without knowing the technical steps to get there, so there is some wiggle room here.

Comment: I like the idea of broading the scope to 'design' so long as we have a good list of valid topics that we consider to be 'design' and people encountering the community would not be confused by this.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a detailed list.

Comment: I like the updated list. I'm iffy about fashion design. I just don't see fashion design related questions belong on this site. but we'll wait and see.

Comment: Yea, fashion may not take off but i've noted how many 'design' type magazines include industrial, fashion and graphic examples and articles. It seems to me, we learn alot from each other just watching for trends and creative solutions- i think Philip proposes a good approach, to allow it on-topic and see how it flys.

Comment: +1 for Design.stackexchange.com

Comment: +1 Rename it. BUT I do not see comic in Design. I love Comic and still buy them, but it is a way of communicate that it is completely different respect to more commercial product that we use for Designing. I read "making comics" of scott mccloud to learn about techiniques, but I still see that it doesn't match with Design issues. I see people coming and talking and questioning about his favourite comics, and I do not think that this is the target here. To me this topic as already an issue of dealing more with technical question for photoshop, than talking about alignment and style

Comment: Disagree with including UI/UX - we already went over this - having two sites cater to the same questions is a bad idea. I'm sure that @Jeff Atwood would agree with that statement completely.

Comment: I agree with Charles. Patrick's suggestion only makes sense if we assume SE sites live in an isolated silo. I'm hitting 4 or 5 SE sites during the day and if I have to wade through cross-posts all the time, it's just going to be annoying. You'll end up driving away more power users which won't be a good thing for the site.

Comment: As for a generic 'design' that might work, but what is design? graphic? fashion? industrial? Architecture? Content? Programming? Engineering? Interior? all fascinating, for sure, but that's an entirely different type of site than one catering to graphic design.

Comment: @Charles Boyung: Yes, we have already been over this. The take away I saw at this point from the Area 51 discussion was that we weren't going to merge the two proposals, but there is nothing to stop GD/D from accepting UI questions. If it works, it works. If it doesn't, then it doesn't.

Comment: @DA01: ". . . but what is design?" Exactly. The proposal here is simply a place to start because "design" is such a broad term, and only time will tell which questions flourish and which ones don't. But we have to start somewhere and three months later we still don't have any new and higher voted proposals.

Comment: @Philip - have you seen all of the proposals on Area51 that have gotten closed because they overlap with existing proposals/sites? Exactly how is including UI/UX here any different?

Comment: @Charles Boyung: I'm not going to get into this with you again. Since the discussions here and in Area 51, we've had commentary from Jeff and Robert with no protest to our plans and the site is flagged for a change in scope. We're just waiting for a start time.

Comment: @Philip - also, where is this commentary from Jeff and Robert? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: Is the goal to get site traffic for the sake of traffic, or is it to define a specific group of interests? Making a broader definition of design may bring more folks in, but it's going to be a really loose set of interests. Not sure we'd be any better off.

Comment: @Charles: The reason why I'm not going to get into this with you is because you are rude and obviously have no interest in hearing what anyone else has to say about this. Editorializing with "your precious GD site" and your past insults do nothing to advance the debate and make it clear that you are not going to discuss this in a rational manner. If you continue with that type of negative and derogatory commentary, then I will exercise my privileges as a moderator. Please, for the sake of overwhelmingly congenial tone of the debate from everyone else, take the time to calm down before typing.

Comment: @DA01: I wasn't the one who started the debate over expanding the scope's site, but readership was a primary issue, I think because initial response was low, but also because a lot of design is seen as being cross-disciplinary; a lot of design principles about color, shape, and the like apply to different areas of design. Also, it is rare to find a designer these days who hasn't done both print and web. If you feel the scope I detailed above isn't correct, or too much, I would greatly appreciate you proposing your own. For a change of this magnitude, more opinions from the community is needed.

Comment: @Philip - I am perfectly willing to discuss things. It seems to me that you are either unable to or unwilling to do so. I asked a simple question and you responded with "I'm not going to get into this with you again". Why can't you answer a simple question? So, I ask again - how is including UI/UX in the GD proposal any different than all of the shut down, duplicate proposals?

Comment: @Philip - And where are these discussions with Jeff and Robert? I don't see them here, and I don't see them on Area 51. In fact, the only response I see from Jeff at all regarding this topic is on UX.SE, where he explicitly states that he doesn't believe UX and GD are a good fit together: http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/204/ui-merging-with-graphicdesign/205#205

Comment: I think the '2d' list is probably the most cohesive and easily definable. That said, UX doesn't fit as well as the rest. All of the bullet point 'professions' in that list typically involve a background with an Art and Design degree. UX can, but it also very much a Human Factors/Sociology background. Personally, I think UX and GD go hand in hand and SHOULD be discussed together in the context of interaction design. However, it seems that we want GD to be more than interaction design, plus there's already a UX area on SE. So, In summary, I like the entirety of your 2D list aside from UX.

Comment: @DA01: As someone posted in the UI meta, "There is an overlap, but there is the same overlap with UX Exchange and Stack Overflow, and those are separate" so I don't see an easy answer here. We also allow web design questions, so, really, what would be the lines of delineation here? GD is going to get them, especially after the name change, and my concern is that we are going to end up with a complex set of rules of what gets migrated and what doesn't that few will be able to follow if they even read them. Since you have such high rep in both sites, guidance would be welcome here.

Comment: @DA01: I did, however, notice that UX looks to have been promoted out of beta, at least going by the new design, and when this entire conversation originally happened, it was still in beta which is not an indicator of success. I'm thinking now that if we can get clear guidelines for what can be kept here and what should be migrated, then we can move things over when appropriate.

Comment: @philip...I agree that there is UX and SE overlap as well. Personally, I think all the web-related SE sites should remain under SE and some form of 'major category' navigation above tags should have been created. Granted, that's a huge endeavor and changes the basic structure of SE.

Comment: Not we have much power, but one solution seems to allow questions to show up on different SE sites simultaneously. 'shared' across sites. That'd be an interesting solution as you'd get POVs from different types of people. And the benefit would be no cross posting and splitting of conversations.

Comment: All that said, based on your last comment, it sounds like the chore now is to decide what would stay on GD and what would be passed to UX?

Comment: @DA01: I think that would be the best course of action at this point. I like your use of the word "chore" here.

Comment: Perhaps that should be a new Meta discussion. As a start, I'd say a UX/UI question that is talking about a visual aspect (colors, icons, page layout, etc.) could certainly stay. Questions more about UX theory, perhaps migrated over to UX.

Comment: @DA01: "Perhaps that should be a new Meta discussion." Completely agree.

Answer (score 7):

I think we also need to address the lack of expert answers to expert questions. This quote from Robert Cartaino blog post "[Area 51: Asking the First Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/)"

> It has long been established that no question is too entry-level nor too basic. Everyone is welcome. But, in these earliest days, we are DESIGNING a site for experts. To attract experts, you need a site where people are asking very interesting and challenging questions, not the basic questions found on every other Q&A site. Remember, the pro sites WILL attract the enthusiasts, but not the other way around!
>
> **The earliest questions on a site will set the tone and topic of the site for a long time.**

*(his emphasis)*

We seems to have an overload of photoshop-effects, identify-font, choose-color questions. This was discussed a bit in a thread about [migrating photoshop questions from photo.stack to here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/photoshop-questions) where @Littlemad made this comment:

> I feel a bit undermined as profession to answer question like "how do you do a diagonal in photoshop?" instead of talking about design principle or solutions.

Now i still stand for **not** calling photoshop and other straight-forward questions off topic. But we **do** need to balance these with engaging expert level questions so that the site attracts the expert level users.

i had an attempt yesterday with a [question about design trends though history](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/908/what-are-the-major-design-trends-in-graphic-design-history), my rational being:

1. i was interested
2. academics love to categorize a design aesthetic
3. its not easy to answer

It hasn't yet got the response i hoped for, so i might try a different tack. But i think this is a crucial stage, the site is still young, to be asking questions worthy of expert response.

Comment: I think this is a good point and is a good 'call to arms' for us to try and come up with some good questions to ask.

Answer (score 3):

SE users, in general, seem to be very web-centric folks. GD as it is now seems to get these types of people:

- web designer/developers
- web developers who aren't graphic designers looking for basic help on visual design
- what is this font?

Nothing wrong with that. However, the first group, web designer/developers, likely already frequent most of the SE universe, so you won't be gaining a whole lot of new users there.

The second group ask pretty basic questions, but it's good to have them on board.

The 3rd group...well, there's already sites dedicated to that, but hey, the more the merrier.

The challenge that I see is that the folks that I'd normally see discussing graphic design on a level that other professionals would be interested in are already doing it somewhere else...be it their AIGA chapter site, HOW's forums, Typophile.org, deviantart, any number of the portfolio sites, any number of blogs, etc.

It's going to be a bit of a chicken vs. egg thing...you won't attract a lot of high level GD topics until there are a lot of high level GD folks joining.

Sorry, that's not much of an answer...more of an observation, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, did not know the matter was spawning here as well.. I already made a complex point in [this one](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/should-we-increase-this-ses-scope).

My 2c here, is while matches with a lot of the options I proposed in the other thread, I see moderation problems if you disallow the "too technical" questions. There's a too thin, ambiguous barrier there, that will make many users with closed questions really not undestanding the closing, and possibly upset. I think if you open the scope, need to be prepared for some a bit more technical questions of those matters. Shouldn't hurt, though.